# Python - Reduce dictionary value lists to smaller lists

Tags: python, dictionary, big-o

I have a dictionary whose IDs are recipe IDs and values are lists of ingredients:

```
recipe_dictionary  = { 134: ['salt', 'chicken', 'tomato paste canned'],
                       523: ['toast whole grain', 'feta cheese' 'egg', 'salt'], 
                       12: ['chicken', 'rice', 'parsley']}
```

I also have a static list that contains ingredients that I don't want to repeat during the day:

```
non_repeatable_ingredients = ['egg', 'chicken', 'beef']
```

Right now I go through each value of the dictionary, then loop through ingredient names, compare each name to the **non_repeatable_ingredients** list and I create a list of the shared words. So my reduced size dictionary would look like:

```
   reduced_recipe_dictionary  = { 134: ['chicken'],
                                  523, ['egg'], 
                                  12: ['chicken']
```

This process takes a long time because my real dictionaries and ingredients lists are long. Is there a faster way to do this than the one below?

This is the **get_reduced_meal_plans_dictionry** method:

```
reduced_meal_plans_dictionary = {}

# For each recipe
for recipe in meal_plans_dictionary:

    # Temp list for overlapp ingredients found for each recipe
    overlapped_ingredients_list = []

    # For each complete name of ingredient in the recipe
    for ingredient_complete_name in meal_plans_dictionary[recipe]:

        # Clean up the ingredient name as it sometimes involves comma, parentheses or spaces
        ingredient_string = ingredient_complete_name.replace(',', '').replace('(', '').replace(')', '').lower().strip()

        # Compare each ingredient name against the list of ingredients that shall not repeated in a day
        for each in PROTEIN_TAGS:

            # Compute the partial similarity
            partial_similarity = fuzz.partial_ratio(ingredient_string, each.lower())

            # If above 90, means one of the ingredients in the PROTEIN_TAGS exists in this recipe
            if partial_similarity > 90:
                # Make a list of such ingredients for this recipe
                overlapped_ingredients_list.append(each.lower())

    # Place the recipe ID as the key and the reduced overlapped list as the value
    reduced_meal_plans_dictionary[recipe] = overlapped_ingredients_list
```

I am using replace and similarity ratio because ingredient names are not as clean my example; for example, I could have egg or boiled egg as one ingredient.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, change your ingredients to be dictionaries instead of lists. Then your matching keys not searching arrays.

Comment: Thank you Rob. This could be a good method if I could make non_repeatable_ingredients list also a dictionary but I can't do that and I can't make that manually now as well as the list of ingredients is long.

Comment: Why can't non_repeatable_ingredients be a dictionary?

Comment: Because we have multiple names, even for one ingredient - it is explained in the Q.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a combination of regex and an defaultdict, you can get exactly what you're looking for. This approach uses regex to reduce the number of `for` loops needed.

Note I've adjusted key `12` to show that it will get both matches.

```
recipe_dictionary  = { 134: ['salt', 'chicken', 'tomato paste canned'],
                        523: ['toast whole grain', 'feta cheese', 'egg', 'salt'],
                        12: ['whole chicken', 'rice', 'parsley', 'egg']}
non_repeatable_ingredients = ['egg', 'chicken', 'beef']
non_repeat = '(' + '|'.join(non_repeatable_ingredients) + ')'

d = defaultdict(list)
for k, j in recipe_dictionary.items():
     for i in j:
            m = re.search(non_repeat, i)
            if m:
                d[k].append(m.groups()[0])
d
defaultdict(list, {134: ['chicken'], 523: ['egg'], 12: ['chicken', 'egg']})
```

Comment: This actually works. Thank you. I mean I do get the reduced dictionary now, my concern was that it takes a long time because of for loops. I have 3 and this one has 2 nested for  loops so I will try this and time it to see if it is faster than my current method. Thanks.

Comment: I tested this method and it is much faster, thank you.

Comment: @fatima no problem. By using regex, you're able to loop through the ingredients once and check for matches instead of looping through every `non_repeatable_ingredient` each time.

Answer (score 1):

How about using sets instead of lists, since each recipe has unique ingredients and order doesn't matter?

Sets are searchable in O(1) constant time, whereas lists are searchable in O(n) time.

[Here are some examples](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/set).

For example:

```
recipe_dictionary = { 
    134: set(['salt', 'chicken', 'tomato paste canned']),
    523: set(['toast whole grain', 'feta cheese' 'egg', 'salt']), 
    12: set(['chicken', 'rice', 'parsley'])
}

non_repeatable_ingredients = set(['egg', 'chicken', 'beef'])
```

You can test for an element's presence in a set like this:

```
for ingredient in recipe_dictionary[134]:
    if ingredient in non_repeatable_ingredients:
        # do something
```

Comment: Might be nice to add a complete implementation with [FuzzySet](https://pythonhosted.org/fuzzpy/fuzz.fset.FuzzySet-class.html#intersection) if you want to keep the fuzzy matching OP used

Comment: Ah, you're right! Thank you. I'll edit my response tonight.

Comment: Again, ingredient names in the recipe_dictionary is very different from ingredient names in non_repeatable_ingredients; which is why I clean up the names and then go by similarity  ratio. I can't simply use >> if ingredient in non_repeatable_ingredients:  << but thank you for the response.

Comment: @fatima I understand. Nonetheless, using sets would be much faster than using lists.

Comment: @ allardbrain, That is right. I try to see if I can use set. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> reduced_recipe_dictionary = {k: list(filter(lambda x: x in non_repeatable_ingredients, v)) for k,v in recipe_dictionary.items()}
>>> reduced_recipe_dictionary
{134: ['chicken'], 523: ['egg'], 12: ['egg']}
>>>
```

If you dont have clean ingredients that does match the items in `non_repeatable_ingredients` list, you can use `fuzz.partial_ratio` from `fuzzywuzzy` module to get the ingredient the closely matches (the ones with ratio greater than say, 80%). Do `pip install fuzzywuzzy` to install it before hand

```
>>> from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
>>> reduced_recipe_dictionary = {k: list(filter(lambda x: fuzz.partial_ratio(v,x) >80, non_repeatable_ingredients)) for k,v in recipe_dictionary.items()}
>>> reduced_recipe_dictionary
{134: ['chicken'], 523: ['egg'], 12: ['chicken']}
```

Comment: All 3 answers would have worked if I had exact same names for ingredients everywhere. As I mention in the question, they are not the same and clean as my example so I clean up the names and use similarity ratio. Thank you.

Comment: @fatima. Updated my answer to work with closely matching  ingredients too

Comment: @ Sunitha Hi, that is exactly, what I used: partial_ratio. Thanks.

Comment: @ Sunitha - I voted up your answer - but I already had this part - it is in my Q. W Stokvis answered my Q and I used that one so I accepted it but thanks for following up.